# The if condition does not work in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I do not get why the code does not write the title when the title is 'Actualitat'

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="page-header">
<?php $title = the_title(); ?>
<?php $act = 'Actualitat'; ?>
<?php if (strcmp($title,$act) !== 0 ): ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

[image: The following code shows that]

Comment: Where is your `the_title()` function?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: it is a  [function from Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<?php $title = the_title(); ?>` to `<?php $title = the_title('', '', false); ?>` because without parameters the function `the_title()` just prints out the title and does not return anything.

Comment: without what parameters, without the third one being false?  I know this, but it's a bit ambiguous

Comment: Yes, without the third parameter. Best to look at the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L32)

Comment: which is where?  it was posted in the comments for the question, but might be nice to include a link..  I'll give you an up vote if you do

Comment: Look at the "source code" words of my previous comment - it is a link that leads directly to the `the_title()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it.